# Share WIFI creating hotspot on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, wifi, wifi-hotspot

I'm not able to create a hotspot in order to share my wifi connection.

I use Linux Mint and I want connect my phone to WIFI through my laptop hotspot.

Comment: "I'm not able" sounds like you tried something, and it didn't work. Could you please include details, including the steps you took and any error messages encountered?

Comment: I've created a New ad-hoc WIFI network with its own SSID but I do not understand what to do after

Answer (score 6):

**If you have wired connection, then do this:**

1. Go to "Network Connections" from bottom-corner networking icon.
2. Click on "Add" and choose "Wi-Fi" option.
3. Give the connection name (to adapter not SSID).
4. Provide a name of your hotspot in SSID field.
5. Set mode to **Hotspot**.
6. Open the terminal and type `ifconfig` (make sure your wireless in on) and there will be usually 3 subsections. 
   Find where it says something like "wl01" and look for "HWaddr". 
   You should have something like `74:de:3c:5i:1e:17`. 
   Copy that address and paste in "Device".
7. Go to "Wi-Fi Security" and choose "WPA & WPA2 personal"
   or any type of security of your preference and set up a good password.
8. Now, go to "IPv4 Settings" and set the "Mode" to "Shared to other computers".
9. Save your settings and connect your hotspot
   from "Connect to Hidden Network..." and you're done.

Answer (score 3):

Instructions for Mint 17:

1. Go to Main Menu -> Preferences -> Network Connections, click on Add and choose Wi-Fi. Choose a network name (SSID), Infrastructure mode. Go to to Wi-Fi Security and choose WPA/WPA2 Personal and create a password. Go to IPv4 settings and check that it is shared with other computers.
2. Do `sudo vi /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME` and change `mode=infrastructure` to `mode=ap`, then save the file.
3. Click on Network Manager near clocks and choose "Connect to hidden wireless network", then choose your connection.

   Source:https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1832

Comment: I've already read it, but it doesn't make sense since I need to connect with my phone to a public valid hotspot (why should I have to connect to a hidden one?), anyway I've tried yesterday and when I connect to this hidden SSID with my laptop...well, it doesn't have any connection! so the method doesn't work

Comment: Sory  could you give a lite more information .
What realy you want do hare network by wifi hotspot from laptop to mobille  ? Or connect laptop to wifi and share network to lan ?

Comment: yes, laptop connected through wifi and simoultaneously sharing a hotspot, so I can connect with my phone through pc to the same network

Comment: `vi` is complicated. `nano` is better in my opinion. Easier to save and close.

Comment: @Sigur try vimtutorial - it's extremeley powerful once you get used to it. And saving that, at least know how to exit ;)

Answer (score 0):

On Linux Mint 19.3 Cinnamon, you can have most of this automated by following these steps:

1. Click the network icon in the bottom right of the dock/menu/taskbar.
2. Select Network Settings from the list menu that appears.
3. A new window will open, on the left-hand side select the WiFi device you'd like to share your hotspot from. (In my case this was WiFi to WiFi sharing, so I selected USB WiFi).
4. After selecting the device, bottom centre section of the window will be a button labelled "Use as hotspot..." click it.
5. That's it! Your computer's hostname is used as an SSID, a random password with be generated, WPA2-Personal will be used as the encryption standard.

The hotspot can be disabled by turning off the selected device.

Comment: There is no "Network Settings" option on Linux Mint 19.3 MATE DE. Please specify your desktop environment. On MATE use "Edit Connections" option.

Comment: Ah sorry I always assume if I don't specify then the default LM will be chosen (Cinnamon), I'm very curious as to why yours doesn't come with a network manager, I suppose you have no Gnome anything then?

Comment: Both are essentially Gnome. MATE is fork of Gnome2, but Cinnamon is derived from Gnome3